# Starlette/FastApi route path components with forward slash

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I have defined a route in Starlette/FastApi -

```
@router.post("/{part}")
def post_method(part):
    return "ok"

@router.post("/{part}/{another_part}")
def another_post_method(part, another_part):
    return "ok"
```

I have some forward slash in the path components, and I want to make the following request to access `post_method`

`curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/path%2Fpath" -H "accept: application/json" -d ""`

results in the 404 error in the Starlette/Fastapi logs.

`INFO:     127.0.0.1:50233 - "POST /api/path/path HTTP/1.1" 404`

How to get the correct path components?

Comment: You could also encode `path%2Fpath` as `path%252Fpath` and decode on the other end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response from Marcelo Trylesinski (Kludex) in fastapi [gitter](https://gitter.im/tiangolo/fastapi?at=5f0438a87eb8383e430d4870):

1. It is not allowed
2. Temporary solution: don't use path

This issue has also been raised on [FastApi Github](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/7328)

Comment: This link is now broken, so it’s hard to understand why using `{param:path}` should be avoided especially given that it’s in the [official FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#path-convertor).

Comment: @bfontaine You can follow the issue on the FastApi Github - https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/7328

Answer (score 16):

You can use Starlette built-in path convertor

```
@app.route("/path/{param:path}", name="path-convertor")
```

Comment: This is not a general solution. I have edited to show why it does not work.